# For information about Bundle Install

Tags: ruby, bundle

I'm running ruby 1.9.3-p125 and rails 3.2.6. When I run `bundle install`, I get the error:

```
 Could not find addressable-2.3.1 in any of the sources
```

My Gemfile.lock contains "addressable (2.3.1)", but it isn't an explicit dependency of my application. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is that the only error message you receive? Is your Gemfile set up properly?

Comment: Copy/paste the content of your gemfile if possible!

Comment: Was Resolved.   Thank you very much.

Comment: (The question was closed, so I can't add this as answer, but:) The addressable gem (v2.3.1) was yanked from rubygems, you'll need to update to addressable 2.3.2. You should be able to run `bundle update addressable` to get the latest version.

Comment: @user1570188 - I've re-opened this if you want to provide your solution and mark as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

addressable-2.3.1 was yanked `http://rubygems.org/gems/addressable/versions/2.3.1`

Use `bundle update` to update Gemfile and it will use addressabe-2.3.2 instead